# Why is an Integer variable assigned null by default?

Tags: java, object, null, primitive-types

I was going through a test on [itester.org](http://itester.org) and found a question which I don't understand:

```
public class Runner 
{
    public static Integer i;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        if (i == 42) {
            System.out.printf("wow");
        }
    }
 }
```

I read before, that integer variable is assigned by default `0`. Why is it assigned `null` here?

Comment: Because it's not a primitive, but an object. The default value for an object is null. When you are doing `i == 42`, it tries to unbox the int value in `i` but since `i` is null, you get a NPE.

Comment: Gotta love Java -- it makes *so* much sense that int and Integer are different data types.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Any reference type (i.e. any variable whose type is Object or a sub-class of Object) has a default value of null. This includes `Integer`.

The primitive `int`, on the other hand, has a default value of 0.

Answer (score 6):

Because the [JLS **4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> For all reference types ([§4.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3)), the default value is null.

And since `Integer` is a *reference* type, it gets `null`:

```
ReferenceType:
    ClassOrInterfaceType
    TypeVariable
    ArrayType
```

<sup>See the link for other types</sup>

Answer (score 5):

The primitive `int` type is assigned 0 by default, but an `Integer` reference is assigned null by default. `Integer` is a [wrapper class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class) -- it's an object, not a primitive type.

You may want to read about [autoboxing and unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) in Java, the process by which Java automatically converts between primitive types and wrapper classes.

Answer (score 2):

In Java Integer is a Object Type. In this sample code, you need primitive type which is int. In Java any Object type/Reference type or any Sub type of object type variable which is not initialized automatically initialized by null. Where as primitive type has a default value.

The reason behind of this is,
Objects provide facilities for polymorphism, are passed by reference (or more accurately have references passed by value), and are allocated from the heap. Conversely, primitives are immutable types that are passed by value and are often allocated from the stack.

Answer (score 1):

All non-primitive non-local variables are assigned to `null`, if not assigned explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Integer is a wrapper class and in this code sample I is reference variable. (In java everything is not object so we use wrapper classes to make object and java perform boxing and unboxing )  All reference variables in java by default null value and all primitive type have its default value (e.g int i -> 0 )

Use:-
Private static int;  then it have 0 value default .